# How to add new icon on 'sidemenu' of customer/account page of Bagisto Ecommerce

Tags: php, css, e-commerce

[image: ![ask.png](/assets/uploads/files/1623399547913-ask.png)]
[image]

- Where these sidemenu icons(address,reviews) is located in Bagisto ?
- How can I add new icon  there for MLM class ?

resources/themes/velocity/views/customers/account/partials/sidemenu.blade.php [Image]
[image]

**resources/themes/velocity/views/customers/account/partials/sidemenu.blade.php**

```
<div class="customer-sidebar row no-margin no-padding">
  <div class="account-details col-12">
    <div class="customer-name col-12 text-uppercase">
      {{ substr(auth('customer')->user()->first_name, 0, 1) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 customer-name-text text-capitalize text-break">{{ auth('customer')->user()->first_name . ' ' . auth('customer')->user()->last_name}}</div>
    <div class="customer-email col-12 text-break">{{ auth('customer')->user()->email }}</div>
  </div>
  @php
  // dd($menu);
  @endphp
  @foreach ($menu->items as $menuItem)
  <ul type="none" class="navigation">
    {{-- rearrange menu items --}}
    @php
    $subMenuCollection = [];

    $showCompare = core()->getConfigData('general.content.shop.compare_option') == "1" ? true : false;

    $showWishlist = core()->getConfigData('general.content.shop.wishlist_option') == "1" ? true : false;

    try {
    $subMenuCollection['profile'] = $menuItem['children']['profile'];
    $subMenuCollection['orders'] = $menuItem['children']['orders'];
    $subMenuCollection['downloadables'] = $menuItem['children']['downloadables'];

    if ($showWishlist) {
    $subMenuCollection['wishlist'] = $menuItem['children']['wishlist'];
    }

    if ($showCompare) {
    $subMenuCollection['compare'] = $menuItem['children']['compare'];
    }

    $subMenuCollection['reviews'] = $menuItem['children']['reviews'];
    $subMenuCollection['address'] = $menuItem['children']['address'];

    unset(
    $menuItem['children']['profile'],
    $menuItem['children']['orders'],
    $menuItem['children']['downloadables'],
    $menuItem['children']['wishlist'],
    $menuItem['children']['compare'],
    $menuItem['children']['reviews'],
    $menuItem['children']['address']
    );

    foreach ($menuItem['children'] as $key => $remainingChildren) {
    $subMenuCollection[$key] = $remainingChildren;
    }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
    $subMenuCollection = $menuItem['children'];
    }
    @endphp
    @php
    // dd($subMenuCollection);
    @endphp

    @foreach ($subMenuCollection as $index => $subMenuItem)
    <li class="{{ $menu->getActive($subMenuItem) }}" title="{{ trans($subMenuItem['name']) }}">
      <a class="unset fw6 full-width" href="{{ $subMenuItem['url'] }}">
        <i class="icon {{ $index }} text-down-3"></i>
        <span>{{ trans($subMenuItem['name']) }}<span>
            <i class="rango-arrow-right float-right text-down-3"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
  @endforeach
</div>

@push('css')
<style type="text/css">
  .main-content-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

</style>
@endpush
```

**packages/Webkul/Shop/src/Config/menu.php**

```
<?php

return [
    [
        'key'   => 'account',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.my-account',
        'route' => 'customer.profile.index',
        'sort'  => 1,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.profile',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.profile',
        'route' => 'customer.profile.index',
        'sort'  => 1,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.address',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.address',
        'route' => 'customer.address.index',
        'sort'  => 2,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.reviews',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.reviews',
        'route' => 'customer.reviews.index',
        'sort'  => 3,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.wishlist',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.wishlist',
        'route' => 'customer.wishlist.index',
        'sort'  => 4,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.compare',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.customer.compare.text',
        'route' => 'velocity.customer.product.compare',
        'sort'  => 5,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.orders',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.orders',
        'route' => 'customer.orders.index',
        'sort'  => 6,
    ], [
        'key'   => 'account.downloadables',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.downloadable-products',
        'route' => 'customer.downloadable_products.index',
        'sort'  => 7,
    ],
    [
        'key'   => 'account.MLM',
        'name'  => 'shop::app.layouts.MLM',
        'route' => 'customer.MLM.index',
        'sort'  => 8,
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own icon within file [add icon](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto/blob/master/packages/Webkul/Velocity/src/Resources/assets/sass/components/app.scss#L849) but the name of class should be the menu key name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).